# Prop isn't being passed through when iterating over children and altering them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm iterating over a form's children to run a function that each child has.

Currently, I'm just returning false to test it.
When the return is false, I want to change one of the child's attributes.

Though the object is being changed with the new prop, the prop itself is being passed on!

The code might illustrate better:

***Main:***

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {TextInput, FormButton, FormWrapper} from '../sharedComponents'


const Main = () => {

    const formValue = useRef('')
  
    return (
        
        <>
            <FormWrapper>

                <TextInput ref={formValue} someAttribute={()=>{return false}} />

                <FormButton text="Submit" />

            </FormWrapper>
        </>

    )
};
```

***sharedComponents:***

```
import { forwardRef, useRef, cloneElement } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const FormLayoutWrapper = styled.form`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    `

export const FormWrapper = ({children})=>{

    const formRef = useRef(null)

    const submit = ()=>{
        if(iterateSomeAttributes()){
            ...
            ...
        }
    }

    const iterateSomeAttributes = ()=>{
        let val = true;
        children.map((el)=> {
            
            if(el!=null && el.props!=null && el.props.someAttribute!=null && typeof el.props.someAttribute === 'function'){
                if(!el.props.someAttribute()){
                    val = false

                    el = cloneElement(el,{data: true})// <--- The object changes but the new value doesn't get passed on to TextInput which still gets data=FALSE
                    
                    //<TextInput {...el.props} data={true} key={'123'}/>//{...el, props: {...el.props, data: true}} <---
                }
            }
        })

        return val

    }

    return <FormLayoutWrapper ref={formRef} onSubmit={submit} action="javascript:void(0);" >
            {children}
        </FormLayoutWrapper>
}


export const TextInput = forwardRef(({data=false}, ref) => {

    console.log("***TextInput Component:",data)//<--- data doesn't change to TRUE

    ...
    ...
    ...
})
```

Comment: Props are immutable. When you are mapping over an array you need to return the mapped-to value. It's not exactly clear to me what you are trying to accomplish other than inject a `data` prop value. It seems to me it'd be a whole lot easier to hold some state in the parent `Main` component and pass `data` and *some* callback down as props to the appropriate children components.

Comment: @DrewReese I've tried, but it's still not working

Comment: Perhaps you could walk us through the code and/or steps that you are wanting to implement? In other words, what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @DrewReese When the submit button is pressed, the form (`FormWrapper`) calls a function `submit` inside of which another function `iterateSomeAttributes` is called. `iterateSomeAttributes` iterates over the form's children focusing on inputs and calling each input's `someAttribute` attribute which is a function. If `someAttribute` return false then that specific input would have its `data` attribute set to true. (which will alter some visual characteristics)

Comment: Ok, that answers what *this* code is trying to do. I meant, overall, what are you trying to do? What is the end goal. If this was a feature request ticket you were creating, what is the feature and requirements? If we understand what your goal is we may be able to better suggest a more optimal/natural solution.

Comment: For example, `Main` passes down an `onSubmit` callback to `FormWrapper`, and `FormWrapper` passes it through to `FormLayoutWrapper` which gets passed down eventually and is called in *some* `form` element's `onSubmit` handler to  signal the form is being submitted. This updates some state in `Main` which is then also passed down as props eventually to this `TextInput` component to set some attribute. Does this make sense? See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for more details on this common pattern.